# round corners with border color

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I am using the following code to get rounded corners as well as a colored outline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<gradient 
    android:startColor="@color/white" 
    android:endColor="@color/white" /> 

<corners 
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" 
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp" 
    android:topRightRadius="2dp"/> 

<stroke
    android:width="5dip"
    android:color="@color/black" />
```

[image: round corners with border color]

The image displays what I'm getting right now. Due to the `stroke`, the rounded corners only lie on the outer edge of the layout and the inner edge of the black outline makes a rectangle with sharp edges. How can I convert the sharp edges to rounded corners?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use the `<shape>` tag to create a drawable in XML with rounded corners. (You can do other stuff with the shape tag like define a color gradient as well).

Following code may help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"
        />

<padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         /> 

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clatify, the border is given by the stroke tag.

Comment: This also works well as the background for say `EditText` items

Answer (score 8):

Use this customize according to your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```