# Android - UI container with edging

Tags: android, user-interface

Somebody knows how I can create container with edging and label in left side of top part?

Example: [screenshots here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cubosoft.sod)

I tried background image, but fault with scaling on tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you was right and there are layouts with rounded corners in the pictures. To make this use the code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

sources: 
[How to make layout with rounded corners..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners) and 
[round corners with border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254561/round-corners-with-border-color)

In this case you will not have scaling problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` to put the background container with the stroke and text + button. And then put a `TextView` with property `android:layout_alignParentTop=true`

```
<RelativeLayout 
    ...>

    <LinearLayout
      ....
      android:background="@drawable/blue_stroke">

        //Text + Button

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView 
       ...
       android:background="@android:color/white"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```